# mongodb print json without whitespace i.e. unpretty json

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm using mongodb 2.2.0 and am trying to print json in a single line as opposed to "pretty" printing using `printjson()` or `find().pretty()`. i.e. I need the documents listed in json format as done by just running the command `db.collection.find().limit(10)`, but I need it done using a cursor in a javascript file as follows:

```
var cursor = db.collection.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(10000);
while(cursor.hasNext()){
    //printNonPrettyJson(cursor.next()); //How???!
}
```

`print()` doesn't do the job, it just prints some gibberish about the object identifier.

The reason I want this is because I'm calling the javascript file from the console and then passing the output to a file as follows:

```
mongo mydatabase myjsfile.js >> /tmp/myoutput.txt
```

EDIT: I want the output as follows:

```
> db.zips.find().limit(2)
{ "city" : "ACMAR", "loc" : [ -86.51557, 33.584132 ], "pop" : 6055, "state" : "A
L", "_id" : "35004" }
{ "city" : "ADAMSVILLE", "loc" : [ -86.959727, 33.588437 ], "pop" : 10616, "stat
e" : "AL", "_id" : "35005" }
>
```

and not like:

```
> db.zips.find().limit(2).pretty()
{
        "city" : "ACMAR",
        "loc" : [
                -86.51557,
                33.584132
        ],
        "pop" : 6055,
        "state" : "AL",
        "_id" : "35004"
}
{
        "city" : "ADAMSVILLE",
        "loc" : [
                -86.959727,
                33.588437
        ],
        "pop" : 10616,
        "state" : "AL",
        "_id" : "35005"
}
>
```

as is given by all the other methods. Again, I need this using a cursor object.

Comment: What is the "gibberish" that `print()` displays on the cursor?

Comment: It prints the object type I guess i.e. `[object bson_object]`

Answer (score 90, accepted):

```
var cursor = db.collection.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(10000);
while(cursor.hasNext()){
    printjsononeline(cursor.next());
}
```

Comment: Nice - changed this to the answer since it's more straight forward

Comment: So much win in this answer!

Comment: but where is the array and the comma ? how can I add them ?

Comment: I think this can be simplified even more using `forEach`: `db.collection.find().sort({_id:-1}).limit(10000).forEach(printjsononeline)`

Answer (score 5):

Try `print(tojson())` - there's an example of printing using a cursor in the [MongoDB docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-operations/#cursors).

```
    var myCursor = db.inventory.find( { type: 'food' } );
    var myDocument = myCursor.hasNext() ? myCursor.next() : null;

    if (myDocument) {
        var myItem = myDocument.item;
        print(tojson(myItem));
    }
```

Comment: Like I said in the question, I don't want to use printjson. Is there an alternative?

Comment: Yeah sorry - it was a copy/paste mishap - I updated to show what I found in the docs.

Comment: Nope, doesn't work. As mentioned here: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/read/#cursor, `printjson()` is an alternative to `print(tojson())`

Comment: What about `db.collection.find().forEach( function(myDoc) { print(myDoc); } );`

Comment: Nope, that just gives me `[object bson_object]` printed again and again

Comment: you can use `print(JSON.stringify(content))`
see details here: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/vsc-mongodb-playground-printjson-doesnt-work-as-expected/109468

Answer (score 3):

You can always do a JS hack for this:

```
> db.tg.find().forEach(function(doc){ print(tojson(doc).replace(/(\r\n|\n|\r|\s)/gm, '')); })
{"_id":ObjectId("511223348a88785127a0d13f"),"a":1,"b":1,"name":"xxxxx0"}
```

Not pretty but works

Comment: Thanks so much! I can't believe there isn't a way to print simple json without spaces! Why is this so hard?!! I've been beating my head on the desk for 2 hours now :(

Comment: @PlastyGrove Indeed I am not sure why they haven't added a minify function either

Comment: Just for completeness, I'd like to add that you can do a regex capture using `()` and use it in the replace param as `"$1"`

Answer (score 2):

With "sort" and "limit" , results can be customised.
with mongoexport --type=csv , result can be printed into csv file, which can be read in xls or in one line.

Answer (score 0):

if each item has {} brackets and there are no others then split it up on the brackets using a regular expression.

This would split it up into {..} {..} items. But if there are nested {} it would not work.

```
var res = s.match(/\{(.|\s)*?\}/g);
if(res) for(var x=0;x<res.length;x++){
    // print  res[x].replace(/\s+/g," ");// w/o spaces
}
```

Comment: Can you print example output? I am unsure what you mean. Each JSON string which represents a document can have a lot more than 2 braces

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use from the command line

```
mongoexport -d $dbname -c $collection -q '{ "id" : -1 }'
```

Not sure you can /sort /limit it