# mongoDB query of a big collection batchSize

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to query and print out the results from my collection but it is too big and batch returns only the first couple hundreds of results or so.

I tried to use batchSize to raise the limit, but every time I try to implement it into a script I got errors.

The number of results I expect is around 15000 records.

I'm running .js script like below:

```
db = db.getSiblingDB('local');
print("START");
result = (db.idlsfcontractroles.aggregate([
  {"$lookup":{
    "from":"idlsfcontracts",
    "localField":"Contract__r_ExternalId__c",
    "foreignField":"ExternalId__c",
    "as":"Con"
  }},
  {"$unwind":"$Con"},
  {"$match":{"Con.Status__c":1,"Con.Type__c":1,"Con.ConductingCompany__c":9}},
  {"$group":{"_id":"$Account__r_MDMExternalId__c"}}
]));
printjson(result);
```

Comment: Loop through it like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14752450/mongodb-print-json-without-whitespace-i-e-unpretty-json

Comment: As per the documentation here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/#differences-between-interactive-and-scripted-mongo you want to loop through the results as opposed to trying to call `printjson` passing the cursor like so: `cursor = db.collection.find();
while ( cursor.hasNext() ) {
   printjson( cursor.next() );
}`

Answer (score 0):

Use skip/limit to page through your results until it is done.

```
var skip = 0;
do {
    result = (db.idlsfcontractroles.aggregate([
         {"$lookup":{
          "from":"idlsfcontracts",
          "localField":"Contract__r_ExternalId__c",
          "foreignField":"ExternalId__c",
          "as":"Con"
         }},
         {"$unwind":"$Con"},
         {"$skip": skip},
         {"$limit": 100},
         {"$match": 
             {"Con.Status__c":1,"Con.Type__c":1,"Con.ConductingCompany__c":9}},
         {"$group":{"_id":"$Account__r_MDMExternalId__c"}}
    ]))
    printjson(result);
    skip += 100;
} while (result)
```